# How to do authentication for an API build with express?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, single-page-application

There are quite a few examples and tutorials on authentication and node out there, as well as several questions on stackoverflow. I'm still struggeling with this subject however when trying to implement authentication for an API which communicates with a SPA. I tried using mean.js as an example as well as to use JWT and passport.js. But even after some days of research and trial and error it is still unclear to me how to achieve the following scenario:

1. A user registers himself with a username (or email) and a password (and gets an email to verify his account)
2. The user logs himself in with the password and username.
3. The user recieves a token as a response
4. The token is used in all following requests which require authentication (and is invalidated after a given amount of time).
5. If the user logs out, the token is invalidated and he gets a new one the next time he logs in.

At a later point of time I also would like to implement Facebook and Google Login (that's why I would like to use passport.js).

I'm glad for any help and also open to suggestions for a better authentication flow.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/). It simplifies the process of handling Auth and all the perils of trying to handle Auth yourself.

Firebase also supports all of the major Auth providers out of the box (Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Firebase is not quite what I need though and has nothing to do with what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the node-example of [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer):
https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/node/server.js#L36

You store password and username to the database on signup.

For logging in one can you simply compare the  (hashed) password with the proved one and send back a token you create via `jwt.encode` ([jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)).

After that you append the token to your requests (in the header is probably the best way) and check its validity via `jwt.decode(token, TOKEN_SECRET)`